# NEO4J: get movies where some actors of a given did not act

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using the movie graph, I have the following question: `movies where Keanu Reeves AND Robin Williams did not act?`

To solve this I have these two queries:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person)
WITH m, collect(p) as actors
WHERE NONE (actor in actors WHERE actor.name IN ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams','Frank Langella'])
RETURN m
```

Or:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NONE(n in ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams','Frank Langella'] WHERE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name:n}))
RETURN m
```

But now I would like to get movies where at maximum one of the three acted. To do that I searched for the predicate functions but I could not find a way to get the count of appearances.

How could I get movies where a percentage of given actors did not act?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine NONE with SINGLE

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WHERE NONE(n in ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams','Frank Langella'] WHERE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name:n}))
OR SINGLE(n in ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams','Frank Langella'] WHERE (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Person {name:n}))
RETURN m
```

Or you could count the pattern appearance

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p:Person))
WHERE p.name in ['Keanu Reeves', 'Robin Williams','Frank Langella']
WITH m, COUNT(p) as count
WHERE count < 2
RETURN m
```